# What is the difference between Windows Azure Active Directory Sync vs Office 365 sync

Tags: active-directory, azure, synchronization, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

My client has half deployed instances of Windows Azure Active Directory, and Office 365 synchronization technologies. I have yet to unravel how much is overlapping, or what isn't.

Based on my experience, it's possible to log into Windows Azure Active Directory and "connect" an instance of it to Office 365.  (I've only seen this with a pre-existing provisioning of O365)

**Question**

With regard to provisioning, attributes that are synchronized, and flexibility of the toolkit, which is a better choice for synchronizing AD, or are they the same?  (O365 vs WAAD)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows Azure Active Directory Sync tool is simply the new name for the Office 365 Directory Synchronization tool - commonly known as DirSync.

There is a difference though; around the same time they changed the name, [support for Password synchronization](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mikehall/archive/2013/06/04/office-365-dirsync-password-synchronization.aspx) from your on-premise Active Directory to Office 365 was implemented - something not previously supported.

Comment: Thanks! They also have a FIM deployment around... since FIM is partially included in DirSync, do you have any suggestions on what to look out for?